# R error message in my bootstrapping & regression code

Tags: r, regression, statistics-bootstrap

I wanted to use bootstrapping & run a regression, but for some reason, it doesn't work. I always get the error message "Anzahl der zu ersetzenden Elemente ist kein Vielfaches der Ersetzungslänge" (in English: apparently I have two sets of elements & I want to change one to the other but they do not match).

Does anyone see what could have gone wrong here:

```
    bootReg <- function(formula,data,indices)
    {
    d <- data[indices,]
    fit <- lm(formula, data=d)
    return(coef(fit))  
    }

    results <- boot(statistic = bootReg, 
    formula = RT ~ Code + Situation + Block, data = reg_df, R = 2000)



    #RT = reaction times (--> numeric)
    #Situation = "lab" or "online" 
    #Block = either 0,1,2 or 3 (--> as characters)
    #Code = each subject's individual code
```

The data in the groups are dependent (= there are RTs from each subject in each situation X block combination)

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I googled the error message & compared my code with other people's (working) approaches, but don't know what happened here anyway.

Comment: Hard to solve without seeing your data. Does `lm(RT ~ Code + Situation + Block, data = reg_df)` give an error? How about `bootReg(RT ~ Code + Situation + Block, data=reg_df, indices = 1:5)`?

Comment: The first one works!!!! Thanks so much!!! <3

Comment: The first command is just a plain vanilla OLS without a bootstrap. I am not sure if that is what you are looking for? Maybe you would get better answers if you attach a part your data to the question using `?dput()`

Comment: I know, but I fixed the formula in the boot() function by adding lm() (I thought the  ```fit <- lm(formula, data=d)``` part would do it automatically but apparently it didn't) and now it works. :-)

Comment: @OttoKässi please post your solution as an answer.  That ensures its availability to future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me, you have to add the lm() in the formula in boot().

```
bootReg <- function(formula, 
                    data, 
                    indices)
{
  d <- data[indices,]
  fit <- lm(formula, data=d)
  return(coef(fit))  
}

results <- boot(statistic = bootReg, formula = lm(RT ~ Code + Situation + Block, data = df), data = df, R = 2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

( I recognize that this is a comment at this point, but I'd like to keep it up as an answer for How-To solve the problem. I'll add specific diagnosis if the OP provides more source info)

A general tutorial for debugging:

First, try `traceback()` to see if an internal call threw the error or `boot` itself did.

Next, take a look at the class and the size of the object returned from your `bootReg` function. Is it exactly what `boot` will accept for the `statistic` input?  Does your `formula` return what you expect it to return (again, class and length)?  Are you certain that  `data` and `indices` inputs are getting fed in the right order to your `formula`?